# SetState() method isn't redrwaing List of items from DB

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I am building an app using SQLITE db where I need to redraw the screen when an item from list is updated. But unfortunately it duplicates the existing data from database and when I restart the app, it only shows the updated data. Here is my _readalldata code:

```
_readNoDoList() async {
 List items = await db.getItems();
  items.forEach((item) {
   // NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem.fromMap(item);
    setState(() {

        _itemList.add(NoDoItem.map(item));
    });
   // print("Db items: ${noDoItem.itemName}");
  });
```

}
which I am calling at:

```
FlatButton(
         onPressed: () async {
           NoDoItem newItemUpdated = NoDoItem.fromMap(
               {
                 "itemName": _textEditingController.text,
                 "dateCreated" : dateFormatted(),
                 "id" : item.id
               });

            
            await db.updateItem(newItemUpdated); //updating the item
            setState(() {
              _readNoDoList(); // redrawing the screen with all items saved in the db
            });

           // Navigator.pop(context);

         },
         child: new Text("Update")),
```

but Screeenshot after clicking the update button but before restarting the app is following:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNg8K.png

And after restarting app, it is:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIrR5.png

Where I'm making the Mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rest of the code look like, but from what I can see here you just keep on adding new items to `_itemList` each time you read **all rows** from the database. That way your list starts containing duplicated rows, because they get added to an already existing list each time the database is read.

Possible solution: try resetting the list after function opening to keep only fresh results:

```
  _readNoDoList() async { 
    _itemList = [];
  ...
  ...
```